# Enzyme TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'phoneUtils' in undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

Here I am using the tool **Enzyme**  to test a web application written in ReactJs. I have [this](https://github.com/guidsen/react-enzyme-example/blob/master/tests/Book.js) working and whenever I have tried to run the test for my application I am getting the error response

> /app/js/services/countries/lib/libphonenumber.js:1
>   (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { "use strict";(function(){var aa=this;function l(a,b){var c=a.split("."),d=aa;c[0] in d||!d.execScript||d.execScript("var "+c[0]);for(var e;c.length&&(e=c.shift());){c.length||void 0===b?d[e]?d=d[e]:d=d[e]={}:d[e]=b;}}function m(a,b){function c(){}c.prototype=b.prototype;a.o=b.prototype;a.prototype=new c();a.prototype.constructor=a;a.$=function(a,c,f){for(var g=Array(arguments.length-2),h=2;hc?Math.max(0,a.length+c):c;if("string"==typeof a)return "string"==typeof b&&1==b.length?a.indexOf(b,c):-1;for(;cb?1:a

And following that

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'phoneUtils' in undefined
at l (libphonenumber.js:1:126)
at libphonenumber.js:432:221
at Object.<anonymous> (libphonenumber.js:1:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
at loader (/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:158:5)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:168:7)
at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (CountryHandler.js:4:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
at loader (/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:158:5)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:168:7)
at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
```

In my test script I am not using any arguments called **phoneUtils** and couldn't find a variable or value passing. Since I am new to enzyme tool and ReactJs don't know actually what is happening here. It would be great if someone give a helping hand.

Comment: There could be a possibility you are running a different project? Can you grep for CountryHandler.js and/or libphonenumber.js - I see mentions of these files in the error stack trace.

Comment: No. I am running the same project. But here I guess it must be with the arguments passing. And could n't make out the arguments here.

Comment: I agree with @ctrlplusb. These error messages can't be coming from this, at least not from what's committed. Follow [this search for `phoneUtils`](https://github.com/guidsen/react-enzyme-example/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=phoneUtils) to see there are zero results.